# Using OpenCV cascade of classifier with traffic sign

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

I'm trying to detect some traffic signs like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOTZb.jpg

I managed to isolate the traffic sign (which is, for the moment, always round): http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/06/1422869734-3.jpg

With bad results with SURF for real-time, and tips of a preceding post, I want to use a cascade of a classifier for the detection of the different traffic sign (30,50,70...).

1) Is traffic signs will be nicely recognized to cascade of classifier like faces are? I mean by that, is a traffic sign is susceptible to haar features detection ?

2) Do I need to train one cascade of classifier (one .xml) for each sign? Do I need to put images of 30,70 traffic signs in the false positive of the 50 (
and conversely) ?

3) If I have understood, the positive images have to have the same size, and i need to delete the background ?

Sorry for my english, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that you need to train some Haar detector per traffic sign's shape (one for triangular warning signs, an other one for circular signs, etc.). As a result of detection you will have some candidates for further processing and should be decided whether a candidate is true positive or not.
If it is true positive: additional classification needs to recognize the type of a known shape. This classification can be an ANN algorithm or SVMs.

Answers to your questions:

1. It's strongly depends on the positive/negative database, the features used for training (Haar, LBP, HoG), but I think this cascade structure can be useful for your purposes.
2. Partly answered above. For the negatives: you should use a very different set of images. E.g. landscapes, animals, etc. It's important to collect a large database because most of the negatives will be rejected during the first steps of the training.
3. You need to use same scale (for positives) during the training and it is recommended to use some global transformation for reducing the effect of different lighting conditions. But you don't need to remove the background, just crop the images along the border of signs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, 50 positives and 1000 negatives can be a good sample ? 
"will have some candidates for further processing and should be decided whether a candidate is true positive or not" it is the advanced steps which decide that ?
i will see documentations on ANN and SVMs but i hope I can implement a thing like that.

Comment: And why not keep the image with round detected, (http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/06/1422869734-3.jpg) , then use Haar ?

Comment: I can state only my experience of face detectors. For frontal faces I used a positive database with more than 7.000 elements and negatives around 20.000 elements to get good results.
On the other hand, once you detected a circular sign, you need to recognize it (e.g. it a 50 km/h speed limitations). For this purpose the circular signs should be categorized (e.g. 5 categories: sign categories from 30, 50, 70, 100, 130 km/h limitations) and SVMs can be used for classification.

Comment: So SVMs is just for classification, firstly the sign images should transformed into a vector representation (it can be a consecutive imaging of the matrix, or some global transform can be used before, e.g. LBP) and the model can be formed from them. You don't have to implement these methods for classification. Use GRT for that, here is an example usage of SVMs: http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=GRT.SVM

Comment: Me again :) in your comment, I see that the sign is detected just it isn't accurate enough. You should postprocess your results to refine the detection. Detect circles with Hough around the output of Haar, or use the color information of the borders (it is almost red), etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try that. But a last thing, can you precise what do you mean by "categorize" ?

Comment: sure, once a circular sign would be detected then it should be recognized. So at this point you know this is a sign, but you don't know exactly what and this is SVMs have use for. To train, and use the SVMs for classification you need another training database with the appropriate classes of signs to be recognized. So, I mean "categorize" is e.g. the creation of 5 different sign classes (one for the 30 km/h limitations, ...) and the database will contain 5*30 images with the appropriate labels.