# Set of images of traffic sign for SVM OpenCV training

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

next to this post : [Using OpenCV cascade of classifier with traffic sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274974/using-opencv-cascade-of-classifier-with-traffic-sign)

I had successfully reconized the first part of a traffic sign of speed  limitation(http://t1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/65/96/32/110_F_65963252_Z6Xi2q6Sh00FX7CguV2hoXFfHeEKZLgy.jpg) with a LBP/Haar classifier..

I've created a program for training n-classes with the opencv implementation of SVM. What I need now is a set of images for train all my classes (30,50,70,90..). The goal of that is to detect the "numeric part" of the traffic sign with SVM.

So i'm thinking of taking picture of my traffic signs set already made (for the LBP/Haar Classifier) and extract the "numeric part" only. like this : http://www.noelshack.com/2015-08-1424269769-110-f-65963252-z6xi2q6sh00fx7cguv2hoxffheekzlgy.jpg

1) Is SVM can give me good result with set of image like these (large light variations, etc..) ?

2) Any idea or how many images are needed ?

Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Bow (bag of words) + SVM for solving my problem. It is working fine. I've used same images database as for Haar features.

Comment: B Can you please help me out.!! I'm working on recognition of vehicles.